# Why size and position of html elements are changed when it is embeded in the foreign object of SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, foreignobject

[image]I want to embed Amchart3/Webix charts into the SVG element. First of all I created foreign object in the SVG document, then set its position and size. Then appended Webix chart (which is html element like div and canvas) into the foreign object. It was displayed, however, the size of the chart got bigger. I tried amchart3, it also displayed larger than usual. What is the problem?

```
  var elem = this.el(animEl);
  var parent = elem.parentNode;
  var foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "foreignObject");
  var x = (elem.getAttribute('x'));
  var y = (elem.getAttribute('y'));
  var width = (elem.getAttribute('width'));
  var height = (elem.getAttribute('height'));

  foreignObject.setAttribute("x", x);
  foreignObject.setAttribute("y", y);
  foreignObject.setAttribute("height", height);
  foreignObject.setAttribute("width", width);

  foreignObject.appendChild(chart.getNode());
  parent.appendChild(foreignObject);
```

Comment: Probably the element inside the foreignObject has default size but in  HTML, it iscompressed to fit  in its parent container.

Comment: @mahan you can check the foreign object parameters from this link: https://codeshare.io/G76MQr

Comment: I just created a similar project. The element has the same size in both places. Append `chart` instead. If it did not work,   you should include a codepen/jsFiddle of your code. It did not help.

Comment: @mahan first of all thanks for your time, you can find the code here: https://codepen.io/Rusya1995/pen/oNXvJww

Comment: Guys, I fixed it. The problem was with the viewbox of SVG's. Literally, I created new SVG element, then set its viewbox (calculated from parent SVG's viewbox and parent's height and width). Then appended foreign object into the SVG that I created, then foreign ob. into the my group svg.